# C# entity framework fromsqlraw query with includes (in) instead of where clause

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

What is the correct syntax for varname to make this query work?
I can get it to work with a single variable like

```
string varname = "TOTAL_NORWAY"
```

However, if I want to have a few variables in there, I get an empty array returned:

```
    string varname = "'TOTAL_NORWAY', 'TOTAL_SWEDEN'";
    
   return await _Context.theDataModel.FromSqlRaw(@"
                        select data
                            from data_table 
                            where Variable in ({0})
                            
    
                    ", varname).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: becuase it is translated to `select data from data_table where Variable in ('''TOTAL_NORWAY'', ''TOTAL_SWEDEN''')` ... google for  `"ef core" where in array`

Comment: `string varname = "'TOTAL_NORWAY', 'TOTAL_SWEDEN'";` is a single string, not two values. Parameters are that - parameters to a function, not string substitution placeholders. That's why they protect from SQL injection attacks. Whatever is in those parameters is never included in the query itself, it's sent as separate parameters to the RPC call to the server

Comment: See my blog post here: https://erikej.github.io/efcore/sqlserver/2020/04/20/use-dynamic-sqlparameters-with-fromsql.html

Comment: That's very helpful ErikEJ, thanks. My issue now is that I have additional where clauses that need to be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ErikEJ's post was very helpful.  The solution is not so trivial for someone who doesn't dabble in EF Core regularly.

I also had an extra where clause to consider, and this was done like so for anyone else wondering.

```
var items = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

var parameters = new string[items.Length];
var sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
for (var i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    parameters[i] = string.Format("@p{0}", i);
    sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter(parameters[i], items[i]));
}

sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userid", "userXYZ123"));


var rawCommand = string.Format("SELECT * from dbo.Shippers WHERE ShipperId IN ({0}) and userid = {1}", string.Join(", ", parameters), "@userid");

var shipperList = db.Set<ShipperSummary>()
    .FromSqlRaw(rawCommand, sqlParameters.ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you can combine `FromSqlRaw` with Linq:

```cs
string varnames = new [] { "TOTAL_NORWAY", "TOTAL_SWEDEN" };

var query = _Context.theDataModel.FromSqlRaw(@"
                        select data
                            from data_table");
    
query = query.Where(x => varnames.Contains(x.Variable));
// Add more where clauses as needed
return await query.ToListAsync();
```